# changing the visibility of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div section that have particular attribute(mdxquery), this attribute will be send to a js file and the result will be shown in html, however, i need to have change this query, for it i design different div section which each of them has different query know i want change the visibility of this section by clicking my checkbox and for each checkbox i must have particular div with particular query,this is a piece of my codes,it seems to be true but dont work, whats the problem?

```
   <div class='first query' style="width:80%;" id="mdxQueryEditor"
            dojoType="GeoSOA.Spatialytics.widgets.MdxQueryEditor" title="MDX query editor"
            submitButtonLabel="Submit"
            mdxQuery="SELECT {[Measures].[report]} ON COLUMNS,&#x000A;{[State].[City].members} ON ROWS&#x000A;FROM [ppgis]">
        </div>

<div class='second query' dojoType='GeoSOA.Spatialytics.widgets.MdxQueryEditor' style='width:80%;' mdxQuery='SELECT {[Measures].[report]} ON COLUMNS,&#x000A;{[Boston].[City].members} ON ROWS&#x000A;FROM [ppgis]' submitButtonLabel='Submit'></div>
<div  class='third query' dojoType='GeoSOA.Spatialytics.widgets.MdxQueryEditor' style='width:80%;' mdxQuery='SELECT {[Measures].[report]} ON COLUMNS,&#x000A;{[Allston].[City].members} ON ROWS&#x000A;FROM [ppgis]' submitButtonLabel='Submit'></div>
<div   id="debug" ></div>
```

script:

```
     $("#State").click( function() {
if($("#State").is(":checked")) {
        /*When the checkbox is checked*/
    $('first query').css('display','none');
    $('second query').css('display','none');
    $('third query').css('display','block') ;


    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#State").click( function() {
    if($("#State").is(":checked")) {
        /*When the checkbox is checked*/
        $('first.query').css('display','none');
        $('second.query').css('display','none');
        $('third.query').css('display','block') ;
    }
});
```

OR

```
$("#State").click( function() {
    if($("#State").is(":checked")) {
        /*When the checkbox is checked*/
        $('.query').not('third').css('display','none');
        $('third.query').css('display','block') ;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong, Just try this,

```
 $("#State").click( function() {
     if($("#State").is(":checked")) {
          $('.first,.second').hide();
          $('.third').show();
         }
   });
```

Please read this : [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)